# Gradient with TableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, gradient

I made a gradient for the `tableView` and everything works normally, but when I scroll upwards, a black space appears, how can I fix it, **I know that this is because I made a transparent `tableView`**.
**It is possible and on objective-c**

```
let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
var gradientSet = [[CGColor]]()
var currentGradient: Int = 0

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    gradientSet.append([gradientOne, gradientTwo])
    gradientSet.append([gradientTwo, gradientThree])
    gradientSet.append([gradientThree, gradientOne])



    gradient.frame = self.tableView.bounds
    gradient.colors = gradientSet[currentGradient]
    gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x:0, y:0)
    gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x:1, y:1)
    gradient.drawsAsynchronously = true
    tableView.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)

    animateGradient()

}

func animateGradient() {
    if currentGradient < gradientSet.count - 1 {
        currentGradient += 1
    } else {
        currentGradient = 0
    }

    let gradientChangeAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "colors")
    gradientChangeAnimation.delegate = self
    gradientChangeAnimation.duration = 5.0
    gradientChangeAnimation.toValue = gradientSet[currentGradient]
    gradientChangeAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
    gradientChangeAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
    gradient.add(gradientChangeAnimation, forKey: "colorChange")
}




func animationDidStop(_ anim: CAAnimation, finished flag: Bool) {
   if flag {
      gradient.colors = gradientSet[currentGradient]
      animateGradient()
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend applying the gradient to another UIView that sits behind the TableView. This could be the ViewControllers view, or just a new UIView. Then you only need to make sure you size the UIView to match the table.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are changing the layer of the table view, you should be changing the layer of the parent view controller so :

```
    //change
    gradient.frame = self.tableView.bounds 
    //to
    gradient.frame = self.view.bounds

    //and change
    tableView.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0) 
    //to
    self.view.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)
```

full code should look something like this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, CAAnimationDelegate {

let arr = ["ddd", "sss", "rrr","ddd", "sss", "rrr","ddd", "sss", "rrr","ddd", "sss", "rrr"]

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
var gradientSet = [[CGColor]]()
var currentGradient: Int = 0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    gradientSet.append([UIColor.blue.cgColor , UIColor.red.cgColor])
    gradientSet.append([UIColor.brown.cgColor, UIColor.orange.cgColor])
    gradientSet.append([UIColor.yellow.cgColor, UIColor.gray.cgColor])



    gradient.frame = self.view.bounds
    gradient.colors = gradientSet[currentGradient]
    gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x:0, y:0)
    gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x:1, y:1)
    gradient.drawsAsynchronously = true
    self.view.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)

    animateGradient()

}

func animateGradient() {
    if currentGradient < gradientSet.count - 1 {
        currentGradient += 1
    } else {
        currentGradient = 0
    }

    let gradientChangeAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "colors")
    gradientChangeAnimation.delegate = self
    gradientChangeAnimation.duration = 5.0
    gradientChangeAnimation.toValue = gradientSet[currentGradient]
    gradientChangeAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
    gradientChangeAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
    gradient.add(gradientChangeAnimation, forKey: "colorChange")
}




func animationDidStop(_ anim: CAAnimation, finished flag: Bool) {
    if flag {
        gradient.colors = gradientSet[currentGradient]
        animateGradient()
    }
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return arr.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell()
    cell.textLabel?.text = arr[indexPath.row]
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    return cell
}}
```

Before:
[image_before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L0TbM.gif)

After:
[image_after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wDyMu.gif)